# Unable to open Geopackage on QGIS : .gpkg is not a valid data source

Tags: qgis, python, geopandas, geopackage

I am trying to open two files, they are both coming from this source :

[https://geoservices.ign.fr/rpg#telechargement][1]

(Two first links that I downloaded through FileZilla).

But once the unizpping is done and I try to open the geopackages on QGIS 3.10, I receive this message :

> gpkg is not a valid or recognized data source

I have also tried to open the files with GeoPandas on Python but here is the result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPLE_OpenFailedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
fiona/_shim.pyx in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector()

fiona/_err.pyx in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer()

CPLE_OpenFailedError: sqlite3_open(PARCELLES_GRAPHIQUES.gpkg) failed: unable to open database file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DriverError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13828/2755099948.py in <module>
----> 1 pac = gpd.read_file('PARCELLES_GRAPHIQUES.gpkg')

~\Anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in _read_file(filename, bbox, mask, rows, **kwargs)
    199 
    200     with fiona_env():
--> 201         with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
    202 
    203             # In a future Fiona release the crs attribute of features will

~\Anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    406     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    407         if local._env:
--> 408             return f(*args, **kwargs)
    409         else:
    410             if isinstance(args[0], str):

~\Anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py in open(fp, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vfs, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, **kwargs)
    254 
    255         if mode in ('a', 'r'):
--> 256             c = Collection(path, mode, driver=driver, encoding=encoding,
    257                            layer=layer, enabled_drivers=enabled_drivers, **kwargs)
    258         elif mode == 'w':

~\Anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py in __init__(self, path, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vsi, archive, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, ignore_fields, ignore_geometry, **kwargs)
    160             if self.mode == 'r':
    161                 self.session = Session()
--> 162                 self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
    163             elif self.mode in ('a', 'w'):
    164                 self.session = WritingSession()

fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.Session.start()

fiona/_shim.pyx in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector()

DriverError: sqlite3_open(PARCELLES_GRAPHIQUES.gpkg) failed: unable to open database file
```

If you have any ideas about how to sort this out, I'm in.

**EDIT 1 :**
I tried to run ogrinfo and got the following results :

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalAlgorithmDialog.py", line 139, in parametersHaveChanged
    commands = self.alg.getConsoleCommands(parameters, context, feedback, executing=False)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\ogrinfo.py", line 82, in getConsoleCommands
    raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))
```

  


  [1]: https://geoservices.ign.fr/rpg#telechargement
````

Comment: Can you open the geopackage with ogrinfo?

Comment: No, it doesn't work with ogrinfo